# Back up SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, backup, store

I would like to back up a value in SharedPreferences so that I can read out this value after a reinstall.

My code does not work and I do not know what the mistake is.

MyBackupAgent

```
package com.app.appname;
import android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper;
import android.app.backup.BackupManager;
import android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper{
 static final String PREFS_DISPLAY = "AppName"; 
 private Context context;
 static final String MY_PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "keyToStore"; 

    public MyBackupAgent(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = 
              new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(context, PREFS_DISPLAY);
        addHelper(MY_PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
    }
    
   public void storeData(){
        BackupManager backupManager = new BackupManager(context);
        backupManager.dataChanged();
    } 
}
```

How I store the data:

```
 ...
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("keyToStore", true);
 editor.commit();
 new MyBackupAgent(this).storeData();
 ...
```

How I receive the data:

```
 ...
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
 boolean value = settings.getBoolean("keyToStore", false);
 ...
```

I also added the API in the Android Manifest:

```
<application ...>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong and how it works? Does it really work?

Comment: plz tell me if you found a solution for this

Answer (score 6):

Your backup agent class for SharedPreferences should be something like this:

```
public class MyPrefsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
    // The name of the SharedPreferences file
    static final String PREFS = "user_preferences";

    // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
    static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

    // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
    }
}
```

Then, you must request a cloud backup (it will be done async) with something like:

```
import android.app.backup.BackupManager;
 ...

 public void requestBackup() {
   BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(this);
   bm.dataChanged();
 }
```

and you don't need to manually restore your SharedPreferences as they are automagically managed by the `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper` class.

Besides your backup API key, don't forget to add your backup agent class in your manifest:

```
<application android:label="MyApplication"
             android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent">
```

More info about all this at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html and http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

Comment: I will check it as soon as possible and report the result.

Comment: Does it work? I have all these properly setup. Still not working.

Comment: Where `String PREFS = "user_preferences";` don't forget to change user_preferences to the name of your actual preference file. i.e the one defined in `getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);`