# Is there timeout for storing variables in Android

Tags: android, session, variables, android-activity, global-variables

I keep UserID Variable for my android App in a class so it will be accessible from all app activities

The issue is that sometimes this variable get emptied after some time.

so is there like a session timeout for variables get stored ?

```
    //This is how I set the variable
    ((PubVar) getApplication()).SetVariable("UserID", UserID);

    //This is how I get the variable
    pUserID = ((PubVar) getApplication()).GetVariable("UserID");
```

---

```
public class PubVar extends Application {
private String UserID;

public String GetVariable(String Var){

    Var = Var.trim().toUpperCase();
    if (Var.equals("USERID")) {return UserID;}

    return null;
}

public void SetVariable(String Var, String Value){
    Var = Var.trim().toUpperCase();
    if (Var.equals("USERID")) {UserID = Value;}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time Android OS kill your app and all variables to free RAM. If you want to save this variable properly, you should save it in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: will it store variables no matter how long app was running? will be shared between all activities?

Comment: @asmgx It will remain there practically permanently(until you remove them). Google can even backup your settings. I'm not sure if SP are backed up by default, but [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578547/backup-sharedpreferences-in-android) something about manual backups.