# Backup shared preferences file to cloud

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I'm trying to backup my shared preferences file, made a BackupAgentHelper -

```
public class MyPrefsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
// The name of the SharedPreferences file
static final String PREFS = "favorites";

// A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

// Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
    addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
}
```

on MainActivity -

```
bm = new BackupManager(getApplicationContext());

    public static void requestBackup() {
    bm.dataChanged();
}
```

and when saving the shared preferences calling the requestBackup method -

```
        editor.commit();
    MainActivity.requestBackup();
```

manifest as below-

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent="MyPrefsBackupAgent">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
        android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAI1Ap52upiK6qBdhShe4Diyzti2CLyayVouApfKQ" />
```

it is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18586137/8648705

Comment: Not working....