# retrieving values from SharedPreferences after re-installing and with allowBackup=true using Android Auto backup

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm having trouble retrieving values (on an Android 9.0 device) from shared Preferences after I re-installed the App and while having allowBackup=true.

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="true" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

According to this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

The shared preferences should be restored?

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
    int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("name", "Elena");
    editor.putInt("idName", 12);
    editor.apply();
```

- I have logged into my Gmail account on the (emulator) phone (API 27) and when going to
  the Drive App, Backups, App-data, I see 18 Apps such as Youtube,
  Gmail etc. and also my own App.
- When I go to "Settings > System > Backup" I see the same Apps and also my own App. I load the App, sharedprefs code is executed. I close the App and remove it from memory. And then I press the "Backup now" button:

[image]

To Verify I can see my App in the list and it got backup 0 minutes ago:

[image]

Then I remove and reinstall the App and expect the 2 values (Elena and 12) to be there. But they are erased...

I also tried the same via command line, but also not working:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html#Preparing

```
adb shell
dreamlte:/ $ bmgr enabled
Backup Manager currently enabled
dreamlte:/ $ bmgr list transports
    android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
    com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport
* com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
dreamlte:/ $ bmgr backupnow my.package.name
Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Success
Package nl.dagelijkswoord.android with progress: 1536/309248
Package nl.dagelijkswoord.android with result: Success
Backup finished with result: Success

dreamlte:/ $ dumpsys backup
Backup Manager is enabled / provisioned / not pending init
Auto-restore is disabled
No backups running
Last backup pass started: 1573804513565 (now = 1573806675410)
  next scheduled: 1573819001046
...
1573806051616 : my.package.name

dreamlte:/ $ bmgr restore 1573806051616 my.package.name                                                                                                            
No matching restore set token.  Available sets:
  35e84268c94b7d9c : SM-G950F
  3a8e32898034f8af : SM-G950F
  3e2610c4ea45fb96 : Nexus 5X
done

dreamlte:/ $ bmgr restore 35e84268c94b7d9c my.package.name                                                                                                         
Scheduling restore: SM-G950F
restoreStarting: 1 packages
onUpdate: 0 = my.package.name 
restoreFinished: 0
done
```

2. Remove App
3. Reinstall App and check if the SharedPreferences values are still there.
4. Values are gone...

The behaviour also seems to differ on Samsung devices with Samsung Cloud, but for now let's focus on stock Android.

**UPDATE:**

It wasn't working anymore because I downgraded the version in build.gradle:

```
build.gradle:
versionCode 70
versionName "1.6.1"
```

Even with `android:restoreAnyVersion="true"` in the `AndroidManifest` it would only work when the version was not downgraded.

Comment: This might help you [backup-sharedpreferences-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578547/backup-sharedpreferences-in-android)

Comment: Hello @PraveenSP I want to use Android Auto backup and not the older key/value store version.

Answer (score 1):

By default android system backups all default data if device is connected to a Wi-Fi network (if the device user hasn't opted in to mobile-data backups), try to reinstall the app and connect with WI-FI usually android system sync data once in every 24 hours if any changes are there.
You can also try to specify your own rules for backup like this.

```
`<application 
 android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules">
</application>`
```

and create a xml file and put it in **res/xml directory.**
Inside the file, add rules with the  and  elements. The following sample backs up all shared preferences except device.xml.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
<include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
<exclude domain="sharedpref" path="device.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>`
```

I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: I just want to save sharedprefs, no xml.

Comment: The above code is rules for android system to save data on user drive, its not going to be save as xml , Include & Exclude Tag notify to the system that which data have to sync and save and which data have to exclude in the sync operation.

Comment: I understand but it's unnecessary I think?

Comment: i dont think ,Its unneccessary beacause of when android system boot compleated it checks all the apps rules configured in manifest by default it also sync when allowBackup is true,  but when we write rules android system keeps in local rules and associate it with package name.

Comment: I've added the above XML code but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As per the data back document, you need to create [SharedPreferencesBackupHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html) and follow these [steps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup) to achieve SharedPreferences back up also need to [register](https://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup) the backup services for your case

Comment: Hello, I'm talking about Android Auto Backup, not Android backup service.

Comment: it's related to auto backup only. for the sample you can follow these steps https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-backup-codelab/index.html#0

Answer (score 0):

You didn't turn on the Auto-restore settings as it showed in the console message. You should go to system settings and turn it on. After that, the restoration could work.

Settings -> Backup -> Automatic restore.

BTW, the token you used is not correct. 1573806051616 is a timestamp instead of the token. The token should appear as below:

```
Ancestral packages: none
Ever backed up: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here, the `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` should be the token.

Answer (score -1):

To test restoration, you need to run the below command without removing your app. The restore command will force stop the app, wipe it's data and perform the restore hence simulating the functionality of the Android AutoBackup:

```
bmgr restore <TOKEN> <PACKAGE>
```

`TOKEN` is retrieved from the `logcat` command when running the backup command or from the `dumpsys backup` command. Also you could check the `dumpsys backup` to verify that the backup was created.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html#TestingRestore

Comment: I tried this and edited the answer but the sharedpref values are still gone.

Comment: There are some preconditions to be met for backup. Please check the below link :: https://blog.devknox.io/what-is-android-allowbackup-how-it-affects-your-app/

Answer (score -1):

May this procedure will work for you.
Try to backing up and restoring a user's sharedPreferences. This will backup your preference to any External Storage or device.

When user uninstall app, user should take back up it. Add some logic that if file is present in External Storage or device, restore it back.

use below code to back up your preference.

```
public static void backupUserPrefs(Context context) {
    final File prefsFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs/" + context.getPackageName() + "_preferences.xml");
    final File backupFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
        "preferenceBackup.xml");
    String error = "";

    try {
        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(prefsFile).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupFile).getChannel();

        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

        src.close();
        dst.close();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Backed up user prefs to " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

use below code to restore preference

```
public static boolean restoreUserPrefs(Context context) {
    final File backupFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
        "preferenceBackup.xml");
    String error = "";

    try {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(backupFile);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        Node child = root.getFirstChild();
        while (child != null) {
            if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element element = (Element) child;

                String type = element.getNodeName();
                String name = element.getAttribute("name");

                // In my app, all prefs seem to get serialized as either "string" or
                // "boolean" - this will need expanding if yours uses any other types!    
                if (type.equals("string")) {
                    String value = element.getTextContent();
                    editor.putString(name, value);
                } else if (type.equals("boolean")) {
                    String value = element.getAttribute("value");
                    editor.putBoolean(name, value.equals("true"));
                }
            }

            child = child.getNextSibling();

        }

        editor.commit();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Restored user prefs from " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        return true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to restore user prefs from " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    return false;
}


    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Back up user prefs to " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}
```

then restart your app before these prefrence will take hold

```
if (restoreUserPrefs(context)) {
    // Restart              
    AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
    Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
    System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(context, MainActivityName.class), 0));
    android.os.Process.sendSignal(android.os.Process.myPid(),
    android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
}
```

Comment: Hello, the problem was that it doesn't backup when my versionCode in build.gradle is downgraded. That is why it wasn't working. This much code is not needed to store only a simple string.

Answer (score -1):

**One way to do this is as follows,** 
(Please note, this may be not the best way, but it works!)

Before uninstall the app, take back up of it. Add some logic that if file is present in **External Storage**, restore it back.

> Preferences stored in the SharedPreferences class get saved into /data/data//shared_prefs/_preferences.xml - backing up is easy, you just need to copy the contents of this file to external storage:

```
public static void backupUserPrefs(Context context) {
final File prefsFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs/" + context.getPackageName() + "_preferences.xml");
final File backupFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
    "preferenceBackup.xml");
String error = "";

try {
    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(prefsFile).getChannel();
    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupFile).getChannel();

    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

    src.close();
    dst.close();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Backed up user prefs to " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    return;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    error = e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    error = e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use following code to restore preference

> But restoring provides more of a challenge, since the shared_prefs file isn’t directly writable by the app, and the SharedPrefs class doesn’t directly expose its functionality to serialise from xml. Instead you have to parse the XML yourself and push the values back in. Thankfully the XML file has a straightforward structure, so it’s easy to loop over the elements and turn these back into preferences.

```
if (restoreUserPrefs(context)) {
// Restart              
AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, MainActivityName.class), 0));
android.os.Process.sendSignal(android.os.Process.myPid(),
android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
}
```

**NOTE**: External storage write and read permission required.